# Can't update VM Debian, because my company has PROXY

Tags: proxy, vmware, nat

I have a problema, I have a Debian virtual machine in VmWare with NAT (Host Windows 10), the other thing is, my company have a proxy server and it requires authentication.

If I configure the proxy in Network settings => Netowork proxy on the Debian VM, and then I go to configure the proxy in the Firefox ESR browser, everything is ok, I can navigate in google, github, etc. But if I open a terminal and I try "apt update", it doesn't work.

Any idea; thank you.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt

Comment: Or see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213737